# Oracle Clone/Copy complete Schema with all dependencies and tablespaces

Tags: oracle

Problem to solve, let's say that:
We have a *new clean* install of Oracle 11G R2. 
We want to copy/clone a Schema from another one with all needed Tablespaces and dependencies.
We want to minimize all manual recreation of tablespaces and so on, also some Packages may or may not have dependencies out of that schema - so we need to check for that too.

What would be the best way to do that. Software options are welcomed too, please describe the procedure if you know with what application and how to be done. 
Example: Oracle Sql Developer, such and such steps, at least in brief.

if you know how to make it work with 'EXPDP ... include=tablespace' can you please write the full command for exporting a selected Schema including the Tablespaces and all 'packages/function/trigers...etc' and how to IMPDP that after that.

Thank you very much community.

Comment: if you know how to make it work with 'EXPDP' - um, ok? Show us what you're trying with Data Pump. You're on the right track, although you might need to map tablespaces when moving from A to B. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-F467946E-50B3-4CC0-937A-CC8C18AAF8C1. SQL Developer has both a copy schema wizard AND an interface for Data Pump. For 'large' schemas, Data Pump will almost always be best.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no great way to accomplish this simple-sounding task.  There are a *lot* of potential dependencies that aren't directly tied to the schema - tablespaces, roles, profiles, resource groups, directories, parameters like SMTP_OUT_SERVER being set (and are system packages like UTL_MAIL installed), components (such as Java), and probably lots of other things I can't think of.  Unfortunately this is one of those things that you just have to do through trial-and-error for a complicated schema.

Answer (score 1):

Remap_schema (+ remap_tablespace if you want it) is what you are looking for:

```
expdp schema1/pwd DIRECTORY=dump_dir DUMPFILE=schema1.dmp \
LOGFILE=schema1_exp.log SCHEMAS=schema1

impdp schema2/pwd2 DIRECTORY=dump_dir DUMPFILE=schema1.dmp \
LOGFILE=schema1_imp.log REMAP_SCHEMA=schema1:schema2 \
REMAP_TABLESPACE=(schema1_tab1:schema2_tab1,schema1_tab2:schema2_tab2)
```